# Ruby / Rails- Most efficient way of dividing an array into two groups based on a parameter and displaying both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a 'Coin' model, which has a boolean parameter, 'accepted'. I want to first display all objects that are accepted, followed by a break, then display those which are not accepted (so I don't want to just sort them and display them all). What is the most efficient way of doing this? Below is how I currently have it, but I feel there must be a better way.

```
<% @accepted = @coin_events.select { |event| event.accepted == true } %>
<% @pending = @coin_events.select { |event| event.accepted == false } %>

<% @accepted.each do |event| %>
  <ul><b>Event: </b><%= event.content %></ul>
  <ul><b>Category: </b><%= event.coin.currency_name %></ul>
  <ul><b>Link: </b><%= event.link %></ul>
  <ul><b>Date: </b><%= event.date.strftime('%a %b %d %Y') if defined?(event.date) %></ul>
  <ul><b>Location: </b><%= event.city %>, <%= event.state %>, <%= event.country %></ul>
  <ul><b>Description: </b><%= event.description %></ul>
  <ul><b>Submitted by: </b><%= event.user.username %></ul>
  <% if can? :edit, Coin %>
    <ul><b>Accepted: </b><%= event.accepted %></ul>
  <% end %>

  <div class="btn-group" id="event-buttons">    
    <% if can? :update, event and @coin.moderator == current_user or current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to "View Event", coin_event_path(event.coin_id, event.id), class: "btn btn-default" %>       
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_coin_event_path(event.coin_id, event.id), class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>
    <% if can? :destroy, event and current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", coin_event_path(event.coin_id, event.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Do you want to delete this submission?" }, class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<!-- OTHER STUFF HERE --> 

<% @pending.each do |event| %>

  <ul><b>Event: </b><%= event.content %></ul>
  <ul><b>Category: </b><%= event.coin.currency_name %></ul>
  <ul><b>Link: </b><%= event.link %></ul>
  <ul><b>Date: </b><%= event.date.strftime('%a %b %d %Y') if defined?(event.date) %></ul>
  <ul><b>Location: </b><%= event.city %>, <%= event.state %>, <%= event.country %></ul>
  <ul><b>Description: </b><%= event.description %></ul>
  <ul><b>Submitted by: </b><%= event.user.username %></ul>
  <% if can? :edit, Coin %>
    <ul><b>Accepted: </b><%= event.accepted %></ul>
  <% end %>

  <div class="btn-group" id="event-buttons">    
    <% if can? :update, event and @coin.moderator == current_user or current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to "View Event", coin_event_path(event.coin_id, event.id), class: "btn btn-default" %>       
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_coin_event_path(event.coin_id, event.id), class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>
    <% if can? :destroy, event and current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", coin_event_path(event.coin_id, event.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Do you want to delete this submission?" }, class: "btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) method in Ruby that does exactly what you need.

> `partition { |obj| block } → [ true_array, false_array ]`
>
> Returns two arrays, the first containing the elements of enum for which the block evaluates to true, the second containing the rest.

In your example `partition` can be used like this:

```
@accepted, @pending = @coin_events.partition(&:accepted)
```

Furtheremore, it looks like both HTML blocks are identical. Then seems like a good oppurtunity to create a partial from one of theses blocks:

```
# the new partial `_event.html.erb`
<ul><b>Event: </b><%= event.content %></ul>
<ul><b>Category: </b><%= event.coin.currency_name %></ul>
<ul><b>Link: </b><%= event.link %></ul>
... ...
    <%= link_to "Delete", coin_event_path(event.coin_id, event.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Do you want to delete this submission?" }, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And reuse this partial to render both collections:

```
<%= render @accepted %>
<!-- OTHER STUFF HERE --> 
<%= render @pending %>
```

I advise reading about [Partials in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections).

Comment: This is the better answer as it will iterate over the data only once.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Learn something new every day hanging around you lot!

Comment: @TomDunning - (1) What do you mean 'iterate over the data only once'? (2) Each answer is deficient (or 'good', depending on how you look at it) in complementary manners. The OP in fact poses two questions (most efficient way of #1 'dividing an array' and #2 'displaying both'). One answer removes ~20 lines of redundant code. The other removes one line of code and a query. Given they are complementary, how does one assess either as 'better'?

Comment: @jvillian it's not a query as it's not calling a db, it's iterating through an enumerable. If you improve your answer by using `@accepted, @pending = @coin_events.partition(&:accepted)` then I'll happily change my vote. However if Event is database driven then we'd be better advising the use of a query.

Answer (score 1):

All that html appears to be identical for each type of `event`.

So, do something like:

```
<% @accepted = @coin_events.select { |event| event.accepted == true } %>
<% @pending = @coin_events.select { |event| event.accepted == false } %>

<% @accepted.each do |event| %>
  render partial: 'event', locals: {event: event}
<% end %>

<!-- OTHER STUFF HERE --> 

<% @pending.each do |event| %>
  render partial: 'event', locals: {event: event}
<% end %>
```

And then put all your html into the `_event` partial. (Note: Untested, you may need to fiddle with it.)

Also, please don't put:

```
<% @accepted = @coin_events.select { |event| event.accepted == true } %>
<% @pending = @coin_events.select { |event| event.accepted == false } %>
```

In your view. That should be in your controller.

And, in your controller, it seems like you should be able to do:

```
@accepted = @coin_events.where(accepted: true)
@pending = @coin_events.where(accepted: false)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked with "render parital:" instead of "render_partial".

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. `render_partial` is a custom method I use in my apps. Sorry about that.